# How to host a game-server through a VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have a VPS on which I run an openVPN server. My question is how to host a server(any server, let's take by example a minecraft server) on my home computer(the VPN client) through the VPN's ip? Is it possible? If yes, how? And another question, I'll be protected from ddos attacks if I'll run the server on that way?

Thanks!

Additional info: Yes, I can port-forward on my router and make a server with my external ip address if this helps in answering the question(but I don't know how), and yes, I tried to bind the server to the VPN's IP[while I was connected to my VPN through openVPN client, of course] but it wont work..

My VPS is running Ubuntu 18.04 and I am using Windows to host my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm it is possible if you set your virtual interface as TAP, not TUN. This way you get a layer 2 connection between your PCs, and it will behave like being in the same LAN.

Comment: Alright, your answer really helped me finding a way to host a server through a VPN!
Here's what I did:
1. Read this article: https://jochen.kirstaetter.name/openvpn-on-windows-all-tap-windows-adapters-on-this-system-are-currently-in-use/
2. Downloaded the OpenVPN "community edition" from there: https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/
3. Followed this answer to port-forward the server: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449853/port-forwarding-using-openvpn-client
4. Opened my server(set ip bind to the given VPN local IP)
5. Bam! Tested and worked!

Thank you for your answer!