# How to host a game-server through a VPN Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, router, vpn, forwarding

I have an ubuntu server home server set up on proxmox and I want my home ip address to be forwarded by vpn.

What I mean here is that, for example, to connect to a server, e.g. minecraft, VPN address 205.201.204.203 redirects this query to my local server

I saw a similar topic, but I can't understand it, please help, I'll be super grateful, at first I wanted to redirect it through the router because my router has vpn options er605 tp-link

Edit:
I only have an OpenVPN server set up and the er605 tp-link router connected to it, I didn't do anything on the vm or forward any ports or anything

[image]

Comment: This is called dynamic DNS, or ddns. Your public router likely has a dynamic changing IP. You can use free services (no-ip.com) to get a website address, usually a router or internal device registers it's public internet IP with the service since it changes

Comment: yes, I know there is such a thing and I used it but I don't want to do it because I want to have another ip address more public than my home one because, for example, steam servers show my home address

Comment: Sorry you meant 'port forwarding' which is done on your router. What I mean if your router says this network ports (you have to look up which ports) are handle by this server & forwards them. Not sure if proxmox let's you be a VPN server so friend can connect as VPN client. As a backup plan you are right that you could use the VPN server buil into so routers. Lastly probably unsecure but you could port forward just the Minecraft server stuff, but then anyone in internet could try to join Minecraft server for VPN is the most secure method

Comment: Look, what I mean is that my local ubuntu server machine connects to the VPN server (e.g. placed on hetzner) and shows the hetzner ip and people connect via this hetzner ip but I totally don't know how to do such a redirection I know how to put openvp-server and openvpn-client to connect the local machine to this but I don't know what rules to set for iptables etc

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1631788/how-to-host-a-game-server-through-a-vpn

here is my let's say idea but I don't understand what and how

Comment: Whofta that's probably beyond my knowledge. Might be easier to have friend connect to VPN server on your router. Maybe you are trying to hide your IP address so you can invite random people on Minecraft server?

Comment: just the second option that I want to hide the ip address so that I can invite random people

Comment: You have configured a port forward on the port OpenVPN is running on to your intranet address? It’s not entirely clear what your question is, clarify it, by editing it.

Comment: What about the other question do you not understand. As this question has been clearly asked elsewhere, this is a duplicate, unless and until you can explain how your question is different. Use the EDIT button to make your question unique.